# Webcam capture on web application

Tags: php, html, flash, web-applications, webcam

I need to take a picture from a webcam into a webapp (PHP5/JQuery/HTML5) but I cannot use Flash; Is there a light java applet or any alternative technology for this?.

Comment: What is the target platform?  In Google IO 2010, they showed Android 2.2, which has a modded version of V8.  This modded version of V8 allows you to get input from the Camera.

Comment: -1 for "I don't want to use Flash".  Use the right tool for the job.  Flash has the highest market penetration rate by far and does what you need.

Comment: I'm developing for opensource project (GNU/Linux target), that's why I cannot use flash. Thanks for your quote.

Comment: None of your technologies listed above support Camera as far as I know. This might be a bit much, but can you not get away using Processing(http://processing.org) ? Basically you'll have a Java applet that should also run on on linux. hth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is "HTML5 Device API", which none of the current browser, stable or beta, support it yet.

Other then that you need to write native app, or NPAPI plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Though HTML5 is not recognized by W3c. But you can use JQuery Library to access web cam from a web aliccation. See the following link http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/
You can get source code and demo from here. How to use the code and how to deploy the code.
I hope your problem will be solve.
Thank you!